# getdns API: How do I know if a RESPSTATUS_NO_NAME response is secure?

Tags: dnssec, getdnsapi

I'm using the Python getdns API.

I'm using the extensions:

```
extensions = {"dnssec_return_validation_chain" : getdns.EXTENSION_TRUE}
```

This means that I'm told if the responses are DNSSEC secured with the `dnssec_status` option in the reply dictionary. (The `results.replies_tree` is an array of reply dictionaries.)

A query can have no replies if there is no name (e.g. `results.status==getdns.RESPSTATUS_NO_NAME`).

In this case, how do I know if the `RESPSTATUS_NO_NAME` response is authenticated with DNSSEC?

Answer (score 1):

When the status is `getdns.RESPSTATUS_NO_NAME`, the replies_tree **will** contain replies with an empty `"answer"` section and return code NXDOMAIN.  I.e. `result.replies_tree[0]['header']['rcode']==getdns.RCODE_NXDOMAIN`

When using a dnssec extension, these replies will contain the proof of non-existance in the `"authority"` section (when secure) and **will** contain a `dnssec_status` just as with replies that do contain answers.

When the status was insecure and the `dnssec_return_validation_chain` extension was used, `result.validation_chain` will contain proof of the non-existance of a secure delegation in one of the ancestors of the queried domain.